# Start setInterval when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to start setInterval when user presses a button. Button id is #begin. I have tried various methods but then setInterval doesn't work at all. Any way to get this to work? Thanks!

```
     $(function () {
  count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".first").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: where is your button click event can u share your code, we will help you.

Comment: Please add code according to your question, and try to explain your problem with max of visualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
 
 $('#begin').click(function(){
   count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".first").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 5000);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="begin" value="Start" />
<div class="first">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setInterval(tick, 100);
});

function tick() {
  console.log('tick');
}
```

jQuery one might look something like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  setInterval(tick, 100);
});
```

Good practice would be to store interval, so you can clear it, whenever you need:

```
const interval = setInterval(tick, 100);

// Clear it this way
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

you use JQuery, you can add a callback to click action

```
$("#begin").click(function(event){
    //start your timer like
   var count = 0,
  wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".first").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#begin').click(function(){
 count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4", "Text 5", "Text 6"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $(".text_display").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 5000);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="begin">
Submit
</button>

<div class="text_display">
</div>
```